# Add text to an existing element not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a little problem, I can not add data to an existing element, so here is my Html code ( 1 line ):

```
<div id="lista"></div>
```

And here is my script :

```
var text = "ok";
for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
   text += "<p>text"+i+"</p>";
}

alert(text) // shows the expected data : ok<p>text0</p><p>text1</p><p>text2</p>
document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = text;
```

But nothing is added to my page, And Rather than using innerHtml I used textContent, but it seems it is not working.

I followed a tutorial for begginers but as you can see, I dont get the expected results, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code as presented should work, but in the real thing do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Perhaps your script is running before the page DOM has fully loaded? This is often the case if you load, and run, your JS in the <head> tag. Try loading the JS just before </body>, or wrap the script in a function that runs only when the page has finished loading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is indeed working...](http://jsbin.com/yarajemulo/edit?output)

Comment: Yes I have An error, it tells me that document.getElementById(..) is null .. I dont know why .. :(

Comment: MarsAndBack and Andreas : you were right .. it worked, Thank you.

Comment: Mr Niet : Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your code `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",` to make sure the DOM are loaded before you execute the code.

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 var text = "ok";
 for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
    text += "<p>text"+i+"</p>";
 }

 alert(text) // shows the expected data : ok<p>text0</p><p>text1</p><p>text2</p>
 document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
```